# How to store lists into an array and then return through a viewbag

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

Hello I have a "sites" table that contains 5 sites. Right now it cycles through the array but the `model.offReport` sections keep getting overwritten by the the following site in the list. To prevent this, at the end of the loop I want it to add the new data to the array so that when I return it, it will return the data for all the sites rather than just the last site that is in the array.
 Currently I have a controller method that looks like this

```
    foreach (Site s in sites)
            {

             foreach (OffSiteItemDetails d in s.ItemDetails)
             {

            ViewBag.OffReportColumns += new List<List<string>>()
            {
                s.Name,
                "",
                "",
                "Average Cost",
                "",
                "",
                "Average Cost (With labour)"
            };
            ViewBag.OffReportRows = new List<List<string>>()
            {

                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Parts",
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiPartCost[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiPartCost[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "600000 series",
                    osiOpc6[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "600000 series",
                    osiOpc6[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "700000 series",
                    osiOpc7[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "700000 series",
                    osiOpc7[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "800000 series",
                    osiOpc8[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "800000 series",
                    osiOpc8[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Tools",
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiTools[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                     "",
                     "",
                    osiTools[s.ID].ToString("C2"),

                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "900000 series",
                    osiOpc9[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "900000 series",
                    osiOpc9[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "Other",
                    osiOpco[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "Other",
                    osiOpco[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Components",
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiCompCost[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiLoCompCost[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Items",
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiItemCost[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiLoItemCost[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                },
            };
            ViewBag.OffReporTotal = new List<List<string>>()
            {
                 new List<string>()
              {
                    "Total",
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiTotal[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiFltotal[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                },
            };


       }

 }


            ViewBag.osiGrandTotal = new List<List<string>>()
            {
                 new List<string>()
              {
                    "OSI Grand Total",
                    "",
                    "",
                    ostotal.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    ofltotal.ToString("C2")
                },
            };


            return model;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my view

```
   @foreach (Site s in sites)
        {


            <tr style="color:black">
                @foreach (var col in ViewBag.OffReportColumns)
                {
                    <th>@col </th>
                }
            </tr>

            @foreach (var row in ViewBag.OffReportRows)
            {
                <tr style="color:black">
                    @foreach (var cell in row)
                {
                        <td>@cell</td>
                }
                </tr>
                }


            @foreach (var row in ViewBag.OffReporTotal)
            {
                <tr style="font-size: 20px">
                    @foreach (var cell in row)
                {
                        <td>@cell</td>
                }
                </tr>

        }


        @foreach (var row in ViewBag.osiGrandTotal)
             {
            <tr style="font-size: 20px">
                @foreach (var cell in row)
                {
                    <td>@cell</td>
                }
            </tr>
             }
```

Any suggestions on how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Just set a variable like ViewBag.YourVariable and access it in your view like:

```
@foreach(OffReportColumns column in ViewBag.YourVariable) { ... }
```

Setting the variable in your controller looks like:

```
public IActionResult ControllerMethod()
{
   ViewBag.MyDyanmicVariable = new List<string>()
   {
      "String1",
      "String2",
      "String3",
   };
}
```

Because the ViewBag is dynamic rather than an array of objects, you can put any type in there and the compiler simply trusts you until runtime that you have put the right types in place.

Needs a list of list of strings:

```
ViewBag.OffReportColumns = new List<List<string>();
```

Then in your foreach loop say ViewBag.OffReportColumns.Add(new List ...).  Then you need a foreach within a foreach to get at the data for output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm sorry I'm relatively new to MVC and still figuring things out. When you say "Just set a variable ViewBag.YourVariable " I am a little confused. What would I put in my controller method to accomplish this?

Comment: Added an example to your question.

Comment: Thanks but it still overwrites to return the data for the last site rather than for all of them

Comment: Have to put the entire collection you've generated as the MyDynamicVariable, instead of just the last one.

Comment: I have edited my question to have your suggestion and I also added what my view page looks like. Maybe you can tell me what is wrong about it? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Maybe try taking out your bigger foreach on the Sites in the view.  I don't think it is overwriting.  I think your just spitting out the data over and over.  You've already put together your listings in the controller method.  You don't need to foreach through the Sites again.

Comment: When I take it out it just displays the last site once

Comment: Oh! I see what happens.  Each time you go through the loop you are overwriting ViewBag.OffReportColumns with the next site in the list (eventually the last one).  You need to make your ViewBag.OffReportColumns a list of lists List<List<string>> and use .Add instead of just equals.

Comment: I edited my code. To what I think you mean. Is that correct?

Comment: When I changed it to that I got the error saying "Cannot convert from 'string' to 'systems.collections.generic<List>' " However

Answer (score 0):

Although there is nothing wrong in using a `ViewBag` I strongly advise to limit its use to very little and trivial stuff - that you might need to pass to the page.

As you are using MVC ('Model' View Controller) I strongly suggest to use a Model for this scenario.

With that it mind lets design first.

We need a basic object that will store some string properties - from a quick count it looks like 7 to be sufficient.

Lets call it BaseModel:

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty3 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty4 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty5 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty6 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty7 { get; set; }
}
```

Excuse the lack of naming for the string properties, I will leave that to your doing.

Now what we need is another object to wrap them into your required list.

From another point it appears that we have the following:

1. OffReportColumns
2. OffReportRows
3. OffReporTotal
4. OsiGrandTotal

Therefor we can define the following - let call it MyModel:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Site { get; set; }
    public List<BaseModel> OffReportColumns { get; set; }
    public List<BaseModel> OffReportRows { get; set; }
    public List<BaseModel> OffReporTotal { get; set; }
    public List<BaseModel> OsiGrandTotal { get; set; }

}
```

The property Site is to distinguish them  - will come handy in the view. For simplicity I have used string - as I don't know what your Site class is defined - You can choose type Site for that for that property.

Now my model is an object that encapsulates 4 lists of strings - each list is self-defined   and will contain 8 string properties.

Now we have the basic for our need.

As we require to have a list of a list - we can encapsulate into a new object to contain our list of list and the collection of sites:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }
    public List<string> MySites { get; set;}
}
```

Again for simplicity I have used list of string for our collections of sites - You can choose type `List<Site>` for that property.

In our Index method we can do as following to populate:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        viewModel = new ViewModel
        {
            MyModels = new List<MyModel>(),
            MySites = new List<string>()
        };

        foreach (Site s in sites)
        {
            foreach (OffSiteItemDetails d in s.ItemDetails)
            {
                MyModel model = new MyModel(); 
                model.Site = s.Name; //taking the assumption that Site has a name property?

                //OffReportColumns
                model.OffReportColumns = new List<BaseModel>();
                BaseModel baseModel = new BaseModel
                {
                    MyProperty = s.Name,
                    MyProperty1 = "",
                    MyProperty2 = "",
                    MyProperty3 = "Average Cost",
                    MyProperty4 = "",
                    MyProperty5 = "",
                    MyProperty6 = "Average Cost (With labour)"
                };
                model.OffReportColumns.Add(baseModel);
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                //OffReportRows
                model.OffReportRows = new List<BaseModel>();
                baseModel = new BaseModel
                {
                    MyProperty = "Parts",
                    MyProperty1 = "",
                    MyProperty2 = "",
                    MyProperty3 = "osiPartCost[s.ID].ToString",
                    MyProperty4 = "",
                    MyProperty5 = "",
                    MyProperty6 = "osiPartCost[s.ID].ToString(C2)"
                };
                model.OffReportRows.Add(baseModel);

                baseModel = new BaseModel
                {
                    MyProperty = "",
                    MyProperty1 = "600000 series",
                    MyProperty2 = "osiOpc6[s.ID].ToString(C2)",
                    MyProperty3 = "",
                    MyProperty4 = "600000 series",
                    MyProperty5 = "osiOpc6[s.ID].ToString(C2)",
                    MyProperty6 = ""
                };
                model.OffReportRows.Add(baseModel);

                baseModel = new BaseModel
                {
                    MyProperty = "",
                    MyProperty1 = "700000 series",
                    MyProperty2 = "osiOpc7[s.ID].ToString()",
                    MyProperty3 = "",
                    MyProperty4 = "700000 series",
                    MyProperty5 = "osiOpc7[s.ID].ToString()",
                    MyProperty6 = ""
                };
                model.OffReportRows.Add(baseModel);
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                //OffReporTotal
                model.OffReporTotal = new List<BaseModel>();
                baseModel = new BaseModel
                {
                    MyProperty = s.Name,
                    MyProperty1 = "",
                    MyProperty2 = "",
                    MyProperty3 = "Average Cost",
                    MyProperty4 = "",
                    MyProperty5 = "",
                    MyProperty6 = "Average Cost (With labour)"
                };
                model.OffReporTotal.Add(baseModel);
                ////////////////////////////////////
                ///you might need to continue with the populating process
                ///....
                ///....

                viewModel.MyModels.Add(model);
            }
        }

        return this.View(viewModel);
    }
```

We will return our viewModel to our view and the view will be defined as:

```
@model ViewModel

@foreach (var s in Model.MySites)
{
    <tr style="color:black">
        // return a list of MyModels for the current site
        @foreach (var col in Model.MyModels.Where(c => c.Site == s).ToList())
        {
            foreach (var prop in col.OffReportColumns)
            {
                // display all the properties for
                <th>prop</th>
            }
        }
    </tr>
}
```